How does the Developer Survey calculate "Admired" vs "Desired"?
The Technology section of the Stack Overflow Developer Survey results includes a section titled Admired and Desired, which provides "Admired" and "Desired" percentages for each technology.
It does not, however, define the meaning of those terms or how they are calculated.  I find this very confusing and would like to understand how they are calculated.

There is a Matrix joke about pills in here somewhere, but I'm struggling to make it funny.

Probably related: What is "Worked With vs. Want to Work With" and "Most loved, dreaded, and wanted" in the Developer Survey results?

Someone out there is bound to create a conspiracy theory on how the section is an excuse to keep Rust in the spotlight. (But then we won't hear the end of it in the event that Rust loses the spot.)

JavaScript: 62.3% used, 58.3% admired, 39.8% desired. C#: 27.1% used, 64.1% admired, 21.6% desired. Rust: 12.6% used, 82.2% admired, 28.7% desired. Nim: 0.4% used, 50.5% admired, 0.9% desired.
How to make sense of these numbers? What do they actually mean?

They mean nothing, given the missleading questions that collect this data

@KevinB The question was not that bad: “Which languages have you done extensive development work in over the past year, and which do you want to work in over the next year?” and it had 2 checkboxes per language. However, then the people processing the survey data did something weird to the numbers they gathered.

@Soonts that's the point. they use this messaging every year knowing full well that they're going to use it differently than the way it's worded. This discussion literally repeats every year.

Personally, I don't think the word choice is that bad at all; some had strong feelings against "loved, dreaded, & wanted", but "desired & admired" is much softer by comparison, and doesn't feel even remotely close to "stretching the truth" in any meaningful sense to me– there will always be some interpretation involved here, after all. The biggest fault I see is that "admired" doesn't have a strong implication of "already using" to me... it feels too semantically similar to "desired", I think. I suppose they just liked the rhyme enough to excuse the slightly unfitting usage.

Just because I use a tech now and want to continue using it, doesn't mean I "admire" it. I use C# and .NET at work. I'd continue using those for the foreseeable future. I'm not a huge fan of these but they pay the bills. I don't dislike these technologies enough to go look for a different job, though. The "desired" descriptor is perhaps more apt but not quite right. I might want to use some technology for academic curiosity. I might plan to dabble with it and leave it. Another, I might want to get into. Perhaps even get involved with it professionally. Imposing what users think is misleading.

@VLAZ I suppose that's fair enough; people use, continue to use, or stop using a thing for a great variety of reasons, which aren't really captured by the terms that well. That said, the question does ask "want to use", not "have to", so it'd be totally reasonable to leave that box unchecked for a technology you use for work, which is part of why I don't think it's unreasonable to interpret the responses the way they did. I think people have a tendency to conflate "desire to use" with "enjoy as a technology" too, which are definitely different thoughts.

I do a lot of C++. On some projects I'd like to do more C++ and on some projects I'd like to do less C++. A lot of the time it's just politics.

It would be much better if the survey asked directly: do you admire this tech? do you desire this tech? instead of beating around the bush. Admire and desire are strong words as others have pointed out.

The results blog post helps fill in the gap here. Taking an excerpt the first paragraph from the "Technology Updates" section:

… Python is the most desired language this year (users that did not indicate using this year but did indicate wanting to use next year), overtaking JavaScript. The language that most developers used and want to use again is Rust for the second year in a row with an 83% admiration rate. …

Thus, as explained above:

Desired

Did not use this year, but do want to use it next year.
People who want to use a thing that they don't already.


Admired

Did use this year, and want to continue using next year.
People who want to keep using a thing they already use.



There's also a direct explanation and rationale presented in last year's (2023) survey results section of the same name (since it was brand new that year, replacing the "Most loved, dreaded, and wanted" section from years prior):

… To better gauge hype versus reality, we created a visualization that shows the distance between the proportion of respondents who want to use a technology (“desired”) and the proportion of users that have used the same technology in the past year and want to continue using it (“admired”). …

In terms of the survey questions this year, they asked:

Which [technologies] have you done extensive development work in over the past year, and which do you want to work in over the next year? (If you both worked with the language and want to continue to do so, please check both boxes in that row.)

So desired would be:

[ ] Worked with this year
[x] Want to work with next year

And admired is:

[x] Worked with this year
[x] Want to work with next year

This also implies that charts in the "most popular technologies" section are just looking at the first checkbox in the question ("worked with this year").

Your answer would make sense if they would report count of people. Instead, they are reporting percentages. The key question is, what was the denominator while calculating these percentages?

And another, related interesting question. Why is their admired percentage greater than desired even for unpopular languages like Visual Basic, VBA, or PHP?

You know what, it looks like this might be a little more nuanced than I first thought; I suspect, if it's more complicated than a straight percentage of all respondents like you're saying, that the "admired" percentage is out of people using the technology, rather than all respondents (or ones who answered the question), but I'll gladly dig into it to double check in a bit.

@Soonts my two cents is that the denominator is the number of devs either that took the survey as a whole, assuming this was a select-multiple question on the survey. If not, then the number of devs that answered the question of yes/no desired for each language.

@MrDeveloper It’s not total count of respondents, if it would be we would see very small percentage for exotic languages like Nim. It’s not count of respondents for a particular language either because admired/desired numbers don’t add to 100%, the sum is 111% for Rust and 51.4% for Nim.

The denominator for "Desired" is out of total unique respondents for that particular question, the denominator for "Admired" is the total unique respondents that indicated they used the technology in the past year.
